# Regular expression for 12345-6789

Tags: regex

Trying to figure out an expression for our DLP email scanning tool to pick out a certain string of numbers associated with a specific financial account.  An example of the string is `12345-6789`.  The `-` can be a `.` or just an empty space.  Also, the digits can be any number `0-9`.

Comment: `\d{5}[ .-]\d{4}`?

Comment: Is it consistently 5 digits-4digits?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below reg ex for that.

\d{5}[\s-.]\d{4}

The separator can be a hyphen, dot or a space. The number after the separator is fixed to 4 for now, as per your example. So you can change it accordingly. If you need to specify a range between 4 to 5. Then use the below

\d{5}[\s-.]\d{**4,5**}